# Excel Formula for food order guide

Tags: worksheet-function

I am looking to get from a piece count to a case order, here is my formula:

```
=IF(F3="","",ROUNDUP(MAX(0,E3-F3),0)/6)
```

But i need the difference of E3-F3 to be divided by 6 for example and have the result roundup, i am not able to make it work so far.
In the picture G3 is only showing the decimal and it is not rounding up to the next number, even though i have the ROUNDUP formula.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you want divide before rounding like this:

```
=IF(F3="","",ROUNDUP(MAX(0,(E3-F3)/6),0))
```

Comment: Hi Jasen, it works as intended, thank you so much, i had it right just in the wrong place. thank you again.